# How to start git-gui?

Tags: command-line, git

I've installed `git-gui` tool via `sudo apt-get install git-gui`. But how do I start it? Trying with search or `git-gui` command did not find and UI tool for Git.

Comment: Shouldn't git already have git-gui built in? It says so at http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

Comment: @faizal: It really depends on how the debian maintainers decided to package git, take a look at the list of binary packages created from the [git source package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/git)

Comment: @SylvainPineau ahh that makes sense. I guess installing `git-all` would have installed `git-gui` along with all the other packages related to `git`.

Comment: I usually start Git Gui via gitk, there is a menu option under File->Start Git Gui.  Nice and seamless integration of two graphical Git tools on Linux.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Type `git citool` to start git-gui.

If it gives the error: `git: 'citool' is not a git command`, just install the following package: [git-gui](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=git-gui)

```
sudo apt-get install git-gui
```

Comment: this gives me the error : `git: 'citool' is not a git command.`

Comment: Just install the following package: [git-gui](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/git-gui), `sudo apt-get install git-gui`

Comment: `git gui` works for me.

Comment: This gave me error git: 'citool' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Comment: @LuzanBaral: Please install the following packages: `sudo apt-get install git-gui gitk`

Comment: This advice is completely wrong. I used

Answer (score 37):

Typing it without the dash/hyphen should work:

```
git gui
```

instead of `git-gui`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, run `sudo apt-get install git-gui` first. `apt-get install git` does not install `git gui`.

Answer (score 6):

In terminal type :

```
git gui citool
```

Make one commit and return to the shell when it is complete. This command returns a non-zero exit code if the window was closed in any way other than by making a commit.

```
 git gui citool --amend
```

Automatically enter the Amend Last Commit mode of the interface.

```
git gui citool --nocommit
```

Behave as normal citool, but instead of making a commit simply terminate with a zero exit code. It still checks that the index does not contain any unmerged entries, so you can use it as a GUI version of git-mergetool.

Reference [Site](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gui.html)

Comment: The reference site says `git gui is actually maintained as an independent project, but stable versions are distributed as part of the Git suite for the convenience of end users.` So is it really required to install `git-gui` or should i get it automatically inside `git`? I have done `apt-get install git` on my Ubuntu, but the `git gui citool` does not run. I get the error  `git: 'gui' is not a git command.`

Comment: u need to install git-gui, use `sudo apt-get install git-gui` and then just enter command   `git gui`, everything will work fine.