# How to access a git repository using SSH?

Tags: ssh, git

I have the public key. I think this is needed for the SSH connection to the server where the git repo is located.

Now I don't know how to get the code. Can someone please tell me the complete procedure that I have to do so I get the code?

1. Installing git + related configuration
2. Establish SSH connection
3. Get the repo

Comment: When you establish a SSH connection, it is going to be independent for every server. You should mention what sort of server are you using. For instance, GitHub, BitBucket or a private one.

Comment: @Lucio it is a private one, what do I have to do with the SSH then?

Comment: The procedure in your side (generate the key) is the same. The procedure of deploying your key on the server is what will be different. For that, you will need to ask for help to the server admin.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Setup [Git](http://git-scm.com)**

1. Install it with `sudo apt-get install git` (see [here](http://git-scm.com/download/linux))
2. Configure Git (see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git))

**Implement SSH on GitHub/BitBucket**

1. Generate the SSH key with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096` (see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys))
2. Copy the content of your public SSH key, it is the file `id_rsa.pub` by default
3. Paste the content into your GitHub/BitBucket account on the SSH key section

**Get the repo**

Just clone it:

- GitHub: `git clone git@github.com:YOUR_USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git`
- BitBucket: `git clone git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git`

For more information managing a repo, take a look at the [Git For Humans guide by Lucio Martinez](https://gist.github.com/luciomartinez/11277737).

**GUI Tools**

You can [install git-gui](https://askubuntu.com/q/432163/62483) which is a built-in GUI tool for commit.

For more options, take a look at [the list on the official page](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis).

Comment: thanks Lucio; in your guide you have the assumption that I use GitHub or BitBucket, instead the repo is located at `git@git.<somewebsite.net>:<reponame>` does this change anything?

Comment: Not really, just make sure to mention correctly your server.

Comment: if you want to switch remote URL from [HTTPS to SSH](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh)

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Generate KEY

```
- cd   ~/.ssh

- ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@email.com"
```

NOTE - 
Keys need to be only readable by you:

chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

If Keys need to be read-writable by you:

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Step 2: Check the Contents and copy

```
- cat ~/.ssh/nameOfFile.pub | pbcopy
```

Step 3: Configure your SSH key into Bitbucket.org (similar applies to Github.com) 
GOTO settings => SSHKEY

```
- Add what you copied in Step 2 and give it a name
```

Step 4:  Clone your repository using SSH protocol

```
- git clone git@bitbucket.org:{username}/repo.git

- git clone git@github.com:{username}/repo.git
```

This should work BUT

If you keep getting this error

[
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights

]

Follow this steps.

```
i. ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org OR ssh -T hg@github.com depending on which you are using { This will attempt to create a connection to Bitbucket OR Github Cloud ).

ii. If you do not see a message similar  to (logged in as username.). Go to the next step

iii. ssh-add ~/.ssh/identity (identity is whatever name you saved the file when generating a key)

iv. You will get this message (Identity added: /path to ssh file/.ssh/mywork (youremail@email.com)
v. You can now clone your repository.
```